# Is touchend the phone equivalent of onmouseup in js?

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch, onmouseup

I have my web app working fine with computers, but can't seem to get it to work on mobile phones mainly because the onmouseup isn't being fired off. So I added the touchend event thinking it would be the same, but it didn't help. How do I get the same behavior of onmouseup on the phone?

Basically, I have a range slider and I want the release slider part of it to work on phones

```
  <input id="slider" class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value=50 onmouseup="handleSubmit()" touchend="handleSubmit()"/>
```

I've tried it on mobile safari and chrome... neither work

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to rely on mouseup nor touchend. The input element offers another event which comes in handy: **onchange**.

This input fires as soon the input's value changed - because the user released the slider.

Here's an example:

```js
function handleSubmit(e) {
  console.log(e.value)
}
```

```html
<input id="slider" class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value=50 onchange="handleSubmit(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid... it's supposed to be ontouchend

```
<input id="slider" class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value=50 onmouseup="handleSubmit()" touchend="handleSubmit()"/>
```

still new to js haha